# What is the best place for adding TSConfig in an extension?

Tags: performance, typo3, tsconfig

I see different places for adding Page & User TSConfig in an extension : `ext_localconf.php` and `ext_tables.php`.

I'm using `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig` and `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addUserTSConfig` methods.

Is there a difference in terms of performance between these two locations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ext_localconf.php`, everything else is wrong. It might work (also depending on caching configuration and TYPO3 version) with other solutions but will certainly fail for many other situations and future usage.

Answer (score 0):

The functions may be used in both (according to the PhpDoc header of the functions), but if you look in the system extensions that are shipped with the core you'll see that these two functions are mostly used in `ext_localconf.php` (only `EXT:recordlist` has a call in `ext_tables.php`). Best practise is to place them in `ext_localconf.php`.